# How to call a getter of js file whose name is formed during runtime i.e call a getter of js file with string

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class with few getter whose name are almost same with some difference
 I want to call a getter with its name formed during the runtime as it will reduce lot of lines of codes in our automation scripts

```
   class automationClass extends Page {
/**
define elements
/
get abcObject() {
        return browser.isAndroid ? $("//[@text='clickElement1: ']") : $("//[@text='clickElement1']")
}

get defObject() {
        return browser.isAndroid ? $("//[@text='clickElement2']"): $("//[@text='clickElement2']")
}

get xyzObject() {
         return browser.isAndroid ? $("//[@text='clickElement3']") : $("//[@text='clickElement3']")
}

/*
function to click an object, objParameter parameter coming from another file according to user input
*/
clickObject(objParameter) {
         Var lObj=objParameter+”Object”
this.lObj.click() ////this is not working,,,,,any alternative????
}  
}
```

i have used eval function and was working fine to call a function
but eval is not working for class and getter
_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the []-syntax to get variable properties of an object.

And there were a lot of syntax errors in there:

- missed a closing comment tag
- Var has to be var
- strings are surrounded by `` `'" `` not `”`

```
class automationClass extends Page {
  /**
  define elements
  */
  get abcObject() {
    return browser.isAndroid ? $("//[@text='clickElement1: ']") : $("//[@text='clickElement1']")
  }

  get defObject() {
    return browser.isAndroid ? $("//[@text='clickElement2']") : $("//[@text='clickElement2']")
  }

  get xyzObject() {
    return browser.isAndroid ? $("//[@text='clickElement3']") : $("//[@text='clickElement3']")
  }

  /*
  function to click an object, objParameter parameter coming from another file according to user input
  */
  clickObject(objParameter) {
    var lObj = objParameter + "Object"
    this[lObj].click() ////this is not working,,,,,any alternative????
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,,,,,it helped......

How can we call the getter using the same way which you suggested if getter is of different javascript file

Comment: What do you mean with different file?